# Rearranging/Restructuring Data Frame

Tags: r

I am playing around with the `Generator Output-Capability Month Report` data from the Independent Electricity System Operator `IESO`. It is a publicly available data that shows the capability and output of each major electricity generator in Ontario, Canada. More specifically, I want to see the difference between the capability and the outputs, and how it changes over time.

Unfortunately, I do not like the way that the data is formatted, so I wanted to rearrange/restructure the data frame. But I don't know how to do this, so I was wondering if anyone here could help me with this. I reckon that this isn't going to be easy, but any help would be much appreciated!

If you wish to play around with the actual dataset instead of the simplified dataset that I'll be providing below, feel free to go to [IESO Generator Output Capability Month Report](http://reports.ieso.ca/public/GenOutputCapabilityMonth/) and download `PUB_GenOutputCapabilityMonth_202001.csv` dataset. I obviously prefer that you try this with the actual dataset, but it's your call.

That being said, Table 1 below is the simplified version of the dataset that only shows the first two generators (i.e., Abkenora Hydro unit & Adelaide Wind unit) in the PUB_GenOutputCapabilityMonth_202001.csv file. Note that, under the `Measurement` column, `Available Capacity` for the wind unit is essentially the same as the `Capability` for other types of generators.

**Table 1: Simplified Data**

| Delivery Date | Generator | Fuel Type | Measurement | Hour 1 | Hour 2 | Hour 3 | Hour 4 | Hour 5 | Hour 6 | Hour 7 | Hour 8 | Hour 9 | Hour 10 | Hour 11 | Hour 12 | Hour 13 | Hour 14 | Hour 15 | Hour 16 | Hour 17 | Hour 18 | Hour 19 | Hour 20 | Hour 21 | Hour 22 | Hour 23 | Hour 24 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | ABKENORA | HYDRO | Capability | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 |
| 2020-01-01 | ABKENORA | HYDRO | Output | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 |
| 2020-01-01 | ADELAIDE | WIND | Available Capacity | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 |
| 2020-01-01 | ADELAIDE | WIND | Forecast | 28 | 35 | 32 | 24 | 24 | 20 | 32 | 32 | 26 | 30 | 25 | 21 | 26 | 26 | 37 | 40 | 37 | 39 | 47 | 55 | 49 | 56 | 57 | 57 |
| 2020-01-01 | ADELAIDE | WIND | Output | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 18 | 25 | 29 | 38 | 43 | 34 | 43 | 49 | 57 | 51 | 59 | 58 | 57 |

**Table 2: Slightly More Simplified Version of Table 1 (fewer hours)**

```
JanuaryData = data.frame(`Delivery Date`= c('2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01'),
                         `Generator` = c('ABKENORA', 'ABKENORA', 'ADELAIDE', 'ADELAIDE', 'ADELAIDE'),
                         `Fuel Type` = c('Hydro', 'Hydro', 'Wind', 'Wind', 'Wind'),
                         `Measurement` = c('Capability', 'Output', 'Available Capacity', 'Forecast', 'Output'),
                         `Hour 1` = c('13', '13', '60', '28', '1'),
                         `Hour 7` = c('13', '13', '60', '32', '0'),
                         `Hour 13` = c('13', '13', '60', '26', '25'),
                         `Hour 18` = c('13', '13', '60', '39', '43'),
                         `Hour 24` = c('13', '13', '60', '57', '57')
                         )

View(JanuaryData)
```

Now I want to rearrange/restructure the data and make it look something like Table 3 below. Note that Table 3 is based on Table 2 (i.e., only shows two generators and fewer number of hours). Again, the actual dataset contains dozens of generators and covers all 24 hours in a day by hourly interval (i.e., hour 1, 2, 3, ... , 23, 24). Also, I want to rename wind generator's "Available Capacity" and merge it to `Capability` so I can represent all of them under one `Capability` column instead of needlessly having two separate columns (i.e., "Available Capacity" column for wind generators & "Capability" column for other types of generators) describing essentially the same thing.

**Table 3: Simplified Final Product - Based on Table 2 data**

| Delivery Date | Generator | Fuel Type | Hour | Capability | Output | Forecast |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | ABKENORA | Hydro | 1 | 13 | 13 | n/a |
| 2020-01-01 | ABKENORA | Hydro | 7 | 13 | 13 | n/a |
| 2020-01-01 | ABKENORA | Hydro | 13 | 13 | 13 | n/a |
| 2020-01-01 | ABKENORA | Hydro | 18 | 13 | 13 | n/a |
| 2020-01-01 | ABKENORA | Hydro | 24 | 13 | 13 | n/a |
| 2020-01-01 | ADELAIDE | WIND | 1 | 60 | 1 | 28 |
| 2020-01-01 | ADELAIDE | WIND | 7 | 60 | 0 | 32 |
| 2020-01-01 | ADELAIDE | WIND | 13 | 60 | 25 | 26 |
| 2020-01-01 | ADELAIDE | WIND | 18 | 60 | 43 | 39 |
| 2020-01-01 | ADELAIDE | WIND | 24 | 60 | 57 | 57 |

It would be great if your explanation can be as detailed as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can conditionally mutate the `Measurement` column using `if_else()`, then `pivot_longer()`, and then `pivot_wider()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

JanuaryData %>% 
  mutate(Measurement = if_else(Measurement=="Available Capacity", "Capability",Measurement)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Hour"), names_prefix = "Hour.", names_to = "Hour") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="Measurement", values_from="value")
```

Output:

```
   Delivery.Date Generator Fuel.Type Hour  Capability Output Forecast
   <chr>         <chr>     <chr>     <chr> <chr>      <chr>  <chr>   
 1 2020-01-01    ABKENORA  Hydro     1     13         13     NA      
 2 2020-01-01    ABKENORA  Hydro     7     13         13     NA      
 3 2020-01-01    ABKENORA  Hydro     13    13         13     NA      
 4 2020-01-01    ABKENORA  Hydro     18    13         13     NA      
 5 2020-01-01    ABKENORA  Hydro     24    13         13     NA      
 6 2020-01-01    ADELAIDE  Wind      1     60         1      28      
 7 2020-01-01    ADELAIDE  Wind      7     60         0      32      
 8 2020-01-01    ADELAIDE  Wind      13    60         25     26      
 9 2020-01-01    ADELAIDE  Wind      18    60         43     39      
10 2020-01-01    ADELAIDE  Wind      24    60         57     57
```

Explanation:

1. use `if_else()` to change `Measurement` values to "Capability" if the value of `Measurement` is "Available Capacity"
2. pivot your data into long format to get all the `Hour.<x>` columns into a single column; note the use of `names_prefix="Hour."` here to *remove* this prefix from each of the columns; you could additionally add the option `names_transform = as.numeric` to the `pivot_longer()` call in order to transform the new `Hour` column from character to numeric
3. pivot your data back to wide format, getting the names of the new columns from the "Measurement" column